# background image dissapears when using -margin

Tags: html, css

Been up all night gettin this silly background to show:

Here is the test page:

http://sensenich.bythepixel.com/products/view_propellers

You will see 3 columns in the middle.  When you hover over them, a drop shadow gets added underneath.  I had to set the margin to -10px since the shadow drops outside of the main div. Just take a look and you will see what I mean.  The problem is, any element i move with the margin outside the parent div gets its background cut off..

Any one know a work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duh, I'm silly: `overflow: auto;` was doing it.

Comment: I voted it up because I have made many silly mistakes. We all have.